# How to get Integer value from excel and store in Soap UI properties step

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I have one data in excel which holds numeric value and when I am sending the same value from Excel to Soap UI properties, it's value getting converted into string like below:

In Excel: 
Value of Data column is 200
In Soap UI properties:
Value of Data field is getting changed to 200.0

Can anyone help me to get the same numeric value in Soap UI properties?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputSTream("Excel File Location");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet Sheet = new XSSFSheet("SheetName");
int totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
testRunner.testCase.SetPropertyvalue("totalRows",totalRows.toString())
def int totalcolumn = sheet.getrow(0).getLastCellNum();
def columns = []
def data = []
def rowIndex = testrunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("RowIndex").toInteger();
if(rowIndex<totalRows)
{

    for(int i = 0;i<totalcolumn;i++)
    {

        colData = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(i).toString();
        propdataarray.add(colData)

        testData = sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(i).toString();
        dataArray.add(testData);
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue(columns.get[i],data.get[i]) 

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Show your code if you want help.

Comment: Updated the question with the code.

Comment: Do using [DataFormatter.formatCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) instead of `Cell.toString` to get the cell content exactly formatted as in `Excel`.

Comment: Will  DataFormatter.formatCellValue treat value as integer or String? Because in Soap UI properties step we can set only string value.

Comment: If you would have followed the link I gave, you would have seen it is `public java.lang.String formatCellValue(Cell cell)`. So yes, it returns a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, It is working as expected DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter () ; ColIndex =sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(i); string testdata = formatter.formatCellValue(collindex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Axel Richter said, use `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` to correct the value from the source. Or you can use an abstraction [script](https://gist.github.com/jkeam/4083570) that works very well with Groovy that handles that for you.

As you said, SoapUI only uses string for property values. If you want to correct it on the receiving/use side, you can use this:

```
def propVal = '200.0'

assert propVal instanceof java.lang.String

println propVal.toFloat().toInteger()
assert propVal.toFloat().toInteger() instanceof java.lang.Integer
```

It is generally better to correct the format at source (before storing it in a property).